# check empty or invalid properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have a model with validation properties.  On a post back to server I would like to check if model values are empty or for example dropdownlist should not be have 0 or something!

Comment: This is very basic information that is readily available http://www.asp.net/mvc.

Comment: [MVC validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you have created your models you could do the validation on he model properties.

Example:

```
public class Foo
{
        public long Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter name")]      
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a gender")]     
        public string SelectedGenderId{ get; set; }
}
```

Then in your view under your dropDownList:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> m.SelectedGenderId)
```

**EDIT thanks to @danludwig:**

Then in your controller you can validate the state of your model but doing this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) 
{
   // do your updates/saves
}
```

I hope that's is what you are after.

Comment: Don't forget about the `if (ModelState.IsValid)` check in the controller action.

Comment: Also for dropdown's, use the overload that creates the label option (which has a `null` value) so it works with the `[Required]` attribute - `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedGenderId, Model.GenderList, "-Please select-")